# Can you access an AWS S3 bucket from a google virtual machine?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, cloud

We use an AWS S3 bucket as a drop point for customer files. The google cloud run machine contains the routines needed to access the S3 bucket, reading some files, writing a log and output. Any issues with this ? Has anyone done this in python/java/JavaScript ?

I can't copy the files into Google storage, it both takes too long and opens up a security scenario I just don't want to deal with. A vast number of answers show migration but in my case, I simply want to enable the image to access it. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can access AWS S3 bucket from GCE VM instance by using `gsutil` command which is a part of Google Cloud SDK (you should find it preinstalled on the VM). Have a look on this doc [Using the gsutil command line](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#using_the_gsutil_command_line), add credentials and use `gsutil` to access your data. Please let me know if it's solve your issue and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank you, that was more than enough guidance. It wasn't as simple as I had hoped but we did get it to work.

Comment: I posted an answer, please upvote/accept it if my guidance was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access AWS S3 bucket from GCE VM instance by using `gsutil` command which is a part of Google Cloud SDK (you should find it preinstalled on your VM).

Please have a look at the documentation [Cloud Storage interoperability](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability):

> This page describes various Cloud Storage tools that you can use to work with data stored in other cloud providers.

at the section [Using the gsutil command line](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#using_the_gsutil_command_line) you can find instruction:

> The [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) tool lets you access Cloud Storage from the command line. It can also be used to access and work with other cloud storage services that use HMAC authentication, like Amazon S3. For example, after you add your Amazon S3 credentials to the [.boto configuration file for gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil), you can start using gsutil to manage objects in your Amazon S3 buckets.